# Implementing a Class Called Average as a Subclass of List

Tags: python, list, class, average

The idea is to create a class that can check if all items in a list are integers, and if so, compute the sum of the items as an average. If all items in the list are not integers it will raise a ValueError exception.

This is what I currently have:

```
class AvgList(list):
  def avg(self):
     self.list = []
     for items in self:
        if not isinstance(items,int):
            try:
                pass
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')
        for x in []:
            return sum(x)/len(list)

  def append(self, item):
    newList = list.append(self,item)
    return newList

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.list)


mylist = AvgList()

mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(5)
mylist.append(10)

print(mylist)
print(mylist.avg())
```

Currently when I run it, it returns:

```
[1, 5, 10]
None
```

However, I don't know how to make it return the average. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why have you written `for x in []`? That loop will run zero times.

Comment: `try: pass`? That `except` will never happen.

Comment: your `try/except` block isn't doing anything. You're already checking if integer, and you're not `try`ing anything to catch an exception.

Comment: `return sum(x)...` doesn't do what you think it does, either. I suppose you'll find that out when it crashes.

Comment: Why do you need to subclass? Why not just have a function which calculates the average of a sequence?

Comment: @senshin Because I tried naming my self.list to []. While I was doing that I thought it was weird but it was the end all in a process of trial and error and I just never switched it back before I posted.

PeterWood, I thought so too, but it is a problem in a book I'm using to learn Python. I thought this seemed like an odd problem to begin with but I guess the idea is more important than the problem it's wanting to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class AvgList(list):
  def avg(self):
     for items in self:
        if not isinstance(items,int):
            raise ValueError('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')

     return sum(self)/len(self)
```

You are not required to override append and len methods as you are not doing anything special in those methods.

Comment: I didn't see what I was doing.

Comment: Can you let me know about that ?

Comment: Yes, this also works, and it's quite similar to my original code. I'm still new to classes so I used other variables when I should've used self. Funny how hindsight is always 20/20. Thanks a bunch, I appreciate it.

Comment: There are really good answers in here but I really like this one for the simplicity and similarity to what I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in []:
    return sum(x) / len(list)
```

this will never work, you have no elements to traverse through and that why you are getting `None` because python functions return `None` when nothing explicitly returned

Answer (score 1):

You have quite a lot of junk in there that isn't necessary. You don't need to define your own `append` or `__len__` if you are happy with `list`'s implementations

```
class AvgList(list):
    def avg(self):
        tot = 0
        for item in self:
            if isinstance(item, int):
                tot += item
            else:
                print('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')
        return tot / len(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class AvgList(list):
    def avg(self):
        if all(isinstance(item, int) for item in self):
            return sum(self)/len(self)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')

mylist = AvgList()

mylist.append(1)
mylist.append(5)
mylist.append(10)

print(mylist)
print(mylist.avg())
```

---

```
[1, 5, 10]
5.333333333333333
```

---

```
mylist.append(2.2)

print(mylist)
print(mylist.avg())
```

---

```
[1, 5, 10, 2.2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(mylist.avg())
  File "1.py", line 6, in avg
    raise ValueError('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')
ValueError: Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.
```

Or, you could simplify the code by raising the error when the user tries to `append()` a non-integer:

```
class IntList(list):
    def avg(self):
        return sum(self)/len(self)

    def append(self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, int):
            raise ValueError('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')
        else:
            super().append(item)
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. Could you explain the purpose of having

    [isinstance(item, int) for item in self]

in brackets?

Comment: @Classical31, That's a python construct called a *list comprehension*.  They are very fast and efficient.  List comprehensions are used to create lists from other data.   A list comprehension is like putting a for-loop plus an optional if condition inside brackets.  In this case, the list comprehension produces a list containing True and False values.  An item in the new list is True if the corresponding item in the original list was an integer. The whole line reads pretty naturally:  "If all are instances of int for each item in self". The all()...

Comment: function will stop as soon as it encounters one False value, and return False.

Comment: Changed the *list comprehension* to a *generator expression*, so that the list of True/False values is never created--eliminating the need to traverse the whole list to create those values.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're trying has errrors..
`self.list = []` is not needed (you don't use it anyway)..

This:

```
for x in []:
        return sum(x) / len(list)
```

is also wrong because what you do is iterate over an empty list `for x in []` and then try to return the sum `sum (x)` of what you probably expect to be an integer divided by the len of a class (list is a builtin class).. So even if you were iterating over a real list and not an empty one, you cannot sum(x) because sum is used on lists and not on integers, and you cannot divide by the `len(list)` because list is a class type and `len` cannot parse this thing... Easiest way to do what you want in python is the following:

```
class AvgList(list):
  def avg(self):
      if not all(map(lambda x:isinstance(x, int), self)):
          raise ValueError('Invalid item in list. All items need to be an integer.')
      try:
          return sum(self) / len(self)
      except ZeroDivisionError:
          print('Empty list')
          # here you can either not return nothing 
          # which means None will be returned, or return something else
          return -1
```

no need to do anything else..

Comment: I think you are supposed to reject other numeric types - `float`, `complex`, `fraction.Fraction` etc.

Comment: @paradox, Too late.  :(

Comment: @7stud it handles the zero division error though in case you pass an empty list..

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it a non-member function. Then it could work with any sequence, and it's a lot simpler, too:

```
>>> def average(sequence):
...     if all(isinstance(item, int) for item in sequence):
...        return float(sum(sequence)) / len(sequence)
...     else:
...         raise ValueError('Invalid item in sequence. All items need to be an integer.')

>>> average([1, 2, 3, 4])
2.5

>>> average({1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3})
2.0

>>> average('12345')
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: Invalid item in sequence. All items need to be an integer.
```

However, this doesn't work with generators:

```
>>> average(item for item in [1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```